# Activate a Chrome Extension with a "Browser Action" in Selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests, keyboard-shortcuts

For test purposes I need to use a Chrome extension inside my Selenium tests.
In the picture you just see the extensions button (the puzzle piece) and under that (clicking) there is the extension I want to activate.
[image: ChromeBar]

Since the code of the extension is available I have added an `_execute_browser_action` to the `manifest.json` to activate the extension easily using a selenium ActionChains shortcut.
This is my edited `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "The Extension Name",
  "...", "...",
  "...", "...",
  "...", "...",
  "commands": {
      "_execute_browser_action": {
          "suggested_key": {
            "default": "Ctrl+I",
            "mac": "MacCtrl+I"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

The problem is that I tried running this code but the extension is not triggered (even if I checked the shortcut manually and it works perfectly):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains, Keys

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_extension('./my-extension.crx')
options.add_argument("--load-extension=./my-extension-chromium")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "http://localhost:9000/"

driver.get(url)

ActionChains(driver)\
        .key_down(Keys.CONTROL)\
        .send_keys("i")\
        .key_up(Keys.CONTROL)\
        .perform()
```

The other solution I tested, always without success is with `pyautogui`:

```
import pyscreeze
import PIL
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui

__PIL_TUPLE_VERSION = tuple(int(x) for x in PIL.__version__.split("."))
pyscreeze.PIL__version__ = __PIL_TUPLE_VERSION

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_extension('./my-extension.crx')
options.add_argument("--load-extension=./my-extension-chromium")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "http://localhost:9000/"

driver.get(url)

# Click on extension icon
v = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("./puzzle_piece_icon.png")
print(v)
pyautogui.click(x=v.left, y=v.top, clicks=1, interval=0.0, button="left")
# that click is not working. after that i should click on the extension icon
# ext_icon = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("./extension_icon.png")
# pyautogui.click(x=ext_icon.left, y=ext_icon.top, clicks=1, interval=0.0, button="left")


driver.quit()
```

I would prefer to make the first solution work (with the ActionChains trigger) if it were possible... as I wouldn't have to integrate the `pyautogui` library.
But any other working solution is welcome.

Comment: You might try with element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+ "i");  Use the <body> element.  Or ActionChains(driver)\
        .send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "i")... but make sure the active element is something in the DOM.

Comment: It's an action of the browser to activate an extension, not an element on the page (so, not on the DOM). Anyway I have just tried it without success.

Comment: Selenium can only interact with the DOM.  I was hoping that extension was listening there for ctrl-i.

Comment: Yeah but I think that the shortcut is captured at browser-level (the application) not DOM-level. Anyway even pyautogui is not working even if the coordinates are found well (see variable v).

Comment: not all extensions will be compatible with Selenium.  When you launch a Selenium session and pause it, can you manually click on the button?

Comment: Yeah if i pause (with a debugger for example) I can click the extension and run it normally, and I can even activate it with the shortcut with the keyboard.

Comment: you might try: element = driver.switch_to.active_element then send keys to the element the element.